# Connecting two devices to one phone

Tags: bluetooth, microphone, iphone, headphones

So I have been trying to connect my microphone to my iPhone 5s while connecting another device(a speaker) simultaneously. Is this possible in anyway? Also can I speak on the mic and hear from the speaker when I'm on a phone call. I know we have car headsets and car hands free speakers with built-in mic these days but I was just wondering if it's possible to use two different devices sinultaneously for a phone call.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this by buying a bluetooth speaker and a pluggable microphone. I would recommend using the [Ultra Slim Bluetooth Speaker](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01686O2XK) as the bluetooth speaker (it is available for $50, pretty affordable) and the [Zoom iQ7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00S9WNULM) as your microphone ($99.99). In Zoom iQ7, there is a headphone plug so you might not even need the speaker if you have the Zoom iQ7.